# Where do I get the Healing Bell recipe?

Tags: atelier-meruru-apprentice-of-arland

I'm in New Game+ and looking for the Healing Bell recipe. I have no memory of how I got it my first time through.

I've already crossed 50k people, adventurer and alchemy level 40, lots of development, etc. and I haven't gotten it yet. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Healing Bell recipe is in the book Thermis Astrology, which you get as a reward for raising your Kingdom Rank to 8 (Saturn).

[image: Thermis Astrology]